# Where is this Java class defined : SimpleBindAuthenticationHandler?

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

I am trying to implement some LDAP authentication using the ldaptive library. In their examples they reference a class named SimpleBindAuthenticationHandler, but I cannot find where this class is defined... anywhere! Google doesn't seem to know where it is, nor Github, nor Oracle. I'm truly at a loss for where this class is and I cannot implement the LDAP code as they have given in their example without it.

```
ConnectionConfig connConfig = ConnectionConfig.builder()
  .url("ldap://directory.ldaptive.org")
  .useStartTLS(true)
  .build();

SearchDnResolver dnResolver = SearchDnResolver.builder()
  .factory(new DefaultConnectionFactory(connConfig))
  .dn("ou=people,dc=ldaptive,dc=org")
  .filter("uid={user}")
  .build();

SimpleBindAuthenticationHandler authHandler = new SimpleBindAuthenticationHandler(new DefaultConnectionFactory(connConfig));
Authenticator auth = new Authenticator(dnResolver, authHandler);
AuthenticationResponse response = auth.authenticate(new AuthenticationRequest("dfisher", new Credential("password")));
if (response.isSuccess()) {
  // authentication succeeded
} else {
  // authentication failed
}
```

Comment: The [BindAuthenticationHandler](https://www.ldaptive.org/javadocs/org/ldaptive/auth/BindAuthenticationHandler.html) seems to be what you're looking for. It is one of two implementations of the [AbstractBindAuthenticationHandler](https://www.ldaptive.org/javadocs/org/ldaptive/auth/AbstractBindAuthenticationHandler.html)

Comment: Yes, you are right! It looks like their documentation might be out of sync with the actual API. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if you have worked with configuring ldaptive via jaas, but I just posted a question about it. Maybe you know something...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914310/how-to-configure-ldaptive-to-use-connection-pooling-jaas