# How to configure ldaptive to use connection pooling (jaas)

Tags: java, authentication, ldap

We have an application that uses ldap to authenticate users. We are using https://www.ldaptive.org/ as our ldap client and we are configuring it via a jaas login configuration file.

Here is an example our our jaas login configuration file:

```
ourApplication {
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapLoginModule required
    storePass="true"
    ldapUrl="ldap://ldapserver:10389"
    baseDn="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
    useStartTLS="false"
    bindDn="uid=admin,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
    bindCredential="password"
    userFilter="(uid={user})";
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapRoleAuthorizationModule required
    useFirstPass="true"
    ldapUrl="ldap://ldapserver:10389"
    baseDn="ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=com"
    roleFilter="(member={dn})"
    roleAttribute="cn";
};
```

This works well enough. Over time we have started getting errors, similar to what is described here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/ldap-queries-fail-with-address-already-in-use-error-222201829.html

In case that link goes bad, the complaint is from a confluence user that users are sometimes unable to be authenticated via the ldap server. Errors like this are reported:

```
2010-08-10 13:04:18,277 ERROR [http-80-8] [user.impl.ldap.LDAPUserManagerReadOnly] getUser Error retrieving user: 'Husein.Alatas' from LDAP.
 -- url: /display/Test | userName: Husein.Alatas | referer: http://confluence/display/dashboard/Home | action: notpermitted
com.atlassian.user.impl.ldap.repository.LdapConnectionFailedException: javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldap.atlassian.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect]
    at com.atlassian.user.impl.ldap.repository.DefaultLdapContextFactory.getLDAPContext(DefaultLdapContextFactory.java:93)
    at com.atlassian.user.impl.ldap.search.DefaultLDAPUserAdaptor.search(DefaultLDAPUserAdaptor.java:70)
    at com.atlassian.user.impl.ldap.search.DefaultLDAPUserAdaptor.search(DefaultLDAPUserAdaptor.java:54)
    at com.atlassian.user.impl.ldap.LDAPUserManagerReadOnly.getUser(LDAPUserManagerReadOnly.java:70)
    at com.atlassian.user.impl.delegation.DelegatingUserManager.getUser(DelegatingUserManager.java:68)
    at bucket.user.DefaultUserAccessor.getUser(DefaultUserAccessor.java:146)
...
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: ldap.atlassian.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:200)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:118)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClientFactory.createPooledConnection(LdapClientFactory.java:46)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections.getOrCreateConnection(Connections.java:185)
...
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
...
```

We are getting similar communication and bind errors.

The link above suggests running the

```
netstat -na
```

command on our application server to see if there are a lot of open connections to the ldap server. When I do that I see hundreds of lines that look like this:

```
TCP    129.135.249.138:65525  129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
```

Where the left address is our server:port and the right is the ldap server:port. Ultimately, the port on the left goes to 65535, which is probably what is causing the inability to authenticate: all ports occupied, so cannot communicate.

The atlassian link above points to the ldaptive jaas configuration page for an example of how to configure connection pooling for ldaptive:

https://www.ldaptive.org/docs/guide/jaas.html

Here is the example ldaptive gives for configuring ldaptive to use connection pooling via jaas configuration:

```
ldaptive {
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapLoginModule required
    ldapUrl="ldap://directory.ldaptive.org:389"
    baseDn="ou=people,dc=ldaptive,dc=org"
    bindDn="cn=priviledged_user,ou=services,dc=vt,dc=edu"
    bindCredential="notarealpassword"
    useStartTLS="true"
    userFilter="(uid={user})"
    userRoleAttribute="eduPersonAffiliation"
    dnResolver="org.ldaptive.auth.SearchDnResolver"
    authenticationHandler="org.ldaptive.auth.SimpleBindAuthenticationHandler"
    connectionFactory="org.ldaptive.PooledConnectionFactory"
    cacheId="ldaptive-pooled";
};
```

I have been unable to get this to work. First, I found a couple of errors in the example:

1. There is no SimpleBindAuthenticationHandler class in ldaptive. It
   seems like the most likely class should be
   BindAuthenticationHandler.
2. PooledConnectionFactory's fully qualified class name should be: 
   org.ldaptive.pool.PooledConnectionFactory

After making those changes, my jaas config file looks like this:

```
ourApplication {
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapLoginModule required
    storePass="true"
    ldapUrl="ldap://ldapserver:10389"
    baseDn="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
    useStartTLS="false"
    bindDn="uid=admin,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
    bindCredential="password"
    userFilter="(uid={user})"
    dnResolver="org.ldaptive.auth.SearchDnResolver"
    authenticationHandler="org.ldaptive.auth.BindAuthenticationHandler"
    connectionFactory="org.ldaptive.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
    cacheId="ldaptive-pooled";
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapRoleAuthorizationModule required
    useFirstPass="true"
    ldapUrl="ldap://ldapserver:10389"
    baseDn="ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=com"
    roleFilter="(member={dn})"
    roleAttribute="cn";
};
```

Now, when I run our application and try to authenticate, I see this error in our log file:

```
2019-09-12 14:45:10,229 ERROR (ajp-nio-8009-exec-3)[org.ldaptive.props.AbstractPropertyInvoker] Error invoking public void org.ldaptive.auth.SearchDnResolver.setConnectionFactory(org.ldaptive.ConnectionFactory), on [org.ldaptive.auth.SearchDnResolver@1036972035::factory=null, baseDn=, userFilter=null, userFilterParameters=null, allowMultipleDns=false, subtreeSearch=false, derefAliases=null, referralHandler=null], with params org.ldaptive.pool.PooledConnectionFactory
```

So, it seems like ldaptive is unable to use the pooling configuration that I have defined, mostly per their example.

Does anyone use ldaptive like this (configure via jaas and use pooling)? Does anyone know enough about ldaptive to make a guess as to what is going wrong here and how to configure it correctly?

I guess I should also ask, should pooling in ldaptive solve the apparent exhaustion of ports that I am seeing via netstat -na?

UPDATE:

I was able to get pooling configuration working in my jaas config file:

```
ourApplication {
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapLoginModule required
    storePass="true"
    ldapUrl="ldap://ldapserver:10389"
    baseDn="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
    useStartTLS="false"
    bindDn="uid=admin,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
    bindCredential="password"
    userFilter="(uid={user})"
    dnResolver="org.ldaptive.auth.PooledSearchDnResolver"
    authenticationHandler="org.ldaptive.auth.PooledBindAuthenticationHandler"
    pruneStrategy="org.ldaptive.pool.IdlePruneStrategy{{prunePeriod=PT3M}{idleTime=PT6M}}"
    cacheId="ldaptive-users-pooled";
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapRoleAuthorizationModule required
    useFirstPass="true"
    ldapUrl="ldap://ldapserver:10389"
    baseDn="ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=com"
    roleFilter="(member={dn})"
    roleAttribute="cn"
    dnResolver="org.ldaptive.auth.PooledSearchDnResolver"
    authenticationHandler="org.ldaptive.auth.PooledBindAuthenticationHandler"
    pruneStrategy="org.ldaptive.pool.IdlePruneStrategy{{prunePeriod=PT3M}{idleTime=PT6M}}"
    cacheId="ldaptive-roles-pooled";
};
```

That does seem to have made some difference, but I am still seeing what (seems to me) to be too many connections remaining open between our application server and the ldap server.
Here is an example of netstat -na output:

```
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61285   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61288   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61290   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61292   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61294   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61299   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61301   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61303   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61309   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61311   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61313   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61317   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61319   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61323   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61336   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61338   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61340   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61342   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61344   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61346   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61348   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61350   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61353   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61355   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61359   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61374   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61376   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61378   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61380   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61383   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61385   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61389   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61396   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61398   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61400   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61402   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61404   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61408   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61416   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61419   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61421   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    129.135.28.210:61423   129.135.28.18:10389    ESTABLISHED
```

When I first started investigating this, virtually all of the ports in use on the application server side were consecutive. Now it seems that, at most, every other port is in use and there are even gaps of 2, 3, 4, and more ports. Note that this example was taken almost two hours after the last ldap activity.

Why are these connections remaining so long after ldap activity has stopped?
Should the pooling/pruning configuration have done more to reduce the number of connections? I would have guess that it would have helped more than it has.

Comment: This indicates a connection leak in ldaptive. You can enable connection pooling at the JNDI level by providing a /jndi.properties resource with the appropriate settings, which are documented along with the JNDI LDAP provider. That might help but really it is a bug, and a bad one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. After digging around more on the ldaptive site, I think I’ve seen reference to the same bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the ldaptive docs are transitioning for version 2.
That's why the documentation seems out of sync.
The version 1 docs can be found at http://www.ldaptive.org/v1/

The cause of your problem is this bug:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8217606

The solution for now is to use the UnboundID provider. Update your JAAS config and add the [ldaptive-unboundid](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/ldaptive/ldaptive-unboundid/1.2.4/ldaptive-unboundid-1.2.4.jar) and [unboundid](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/unboundid/unboundid-ldapsdk/4.0.11/unboundid-ldapsdk-4.0.11.jar) jars to your classpath.

```
ourApplication {
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapLoginModule required
    storePass="true"
    provider="org.ldaptive.provider.unboundid.UnboundIDProvider"
    ldapUrl="ldap://ldapserver:10389"
    baseDn="ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
    useStartTLS="false"
    bindDn="uid=admin,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com"
    bindCredential="password"
    userFilter="(uid={user})";
  org.ldaptive.jaas.LdapRoleAuthorizationModule required
    useFirstPass="true"
    provider="org.ldaptive.provider.unboundid.UnboundIDProvider"
    ldapUrl="ldap://ldapserver:10389"
    baseDn="ou=Roles,dc=example,dc=com"
    roleFilter="(member={dn})"
    roleAttribute="cn";
};
```

Comment: Very good. However such a bug is either in OpenJDK only or else was introduced recently into the Sun/Oracle JDK. I have production code that calls `LdapContext.reconnect()` that's been running for ten years with no connection leaks.

Comment: Bug affects java versions 9, 11, 12 and 13. I don't know if the fix will be back ported to any of those versions.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Just today I saw some information about the same bug on the ldaptive site, along with a suggestion to try UnboundID.